# Grid content disappears when selecting Tab Item of another Grid under Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

My project is based on WPF. I have created a canvas Container. Under that container, I have two grids (`gSettings` and `gGrid`).

I have used GroupBox. Under Canvas Container (`gCanvas`), I have created two grids (`gSettings` and `gGrid`). Under `gGrid`, I am using Tab Controls (`tabCtrlDevice`). First time when the Window is loading, it's showing data correctly in both grids, but when I am changing the tab item of tab controls, the second grid i.e. `gGrid` then, `gSettings` is disappears.

Please help to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```xaml
<GroupBox x:Name="DragDropgrpbox" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <ZoomableCanvas x:Name="zoomCtrl">
        <Canvas x:Name="gCanvas">
            <Grid x:Name="gSettings" Canvas.Left="0" Height="613">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="wrapBrdr2"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Name="ImageViewer2" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="116" Height="107" Panel.ZIndex="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="gGrid" Canvas.Left="140" Height="646">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="grdConverterColumn" MinWidth="140" Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="grdPortColumn" Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="wrapBrdr" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <Image Name="ImageViewer1" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="54" Height="49" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblMessage" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                <Run x:Name="step1" />
                                <LineBreak/>
                                <Run x:Name="step2" />
                                <LineBreak/>
                                <Run  x:Name="step3" />
                            </TextBlock.Inlines>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Border><TabControl x:Name="tabCtrlDevice" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <TabItem x:Name="CoriolisMVD" >
                        <TabItem.Content>
                            <UniformGrid x:Name="grdDevices" Columns="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </TabItem.Content>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="DensityViscosity">
                        <TabItem.Content>
                            <UniformGrid x:Name="grdDensityViscosity" Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </TabItem.Content>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="RosemountFlow" >
                        <TabItem.Content>
                            <UniformGrid x:Name="grdRosemountFlow" Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </TabItem.Content>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="Other" >
                        <TabItem.Content>
                            <UniformGrid x:Name="grdOther" Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </TabItem.Content>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
                <!--End Device Tab Controler-->

                <Grid Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6">
                    <UniformGrid x:Name="grdConverters" Columns="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
                <Border x:Name="grdPortsBrdr" Height="500px" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <UniformGrid x:Name="grdPorts" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </ZoomableCanvas>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot struggle, I got a solution:

```
 gCanvas.Children.Add(gSettings);
```

I have resolved it`